# Sorting in Epic/Feature timeline under Backlogs

Tags: azure-devops, devops

Did anyone of you managed to understand or create a sorting of the epic showed when going into Epic/Feature timeline in Devops under Backlogs?

It really seems odd if that is not possible, but as of now I haven't found a solution. It will also be nice to filter out epics?

Thanks in advance!